# pickerView can't load data that fetch in same view controller (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, datamodel

My pickerview cannot load data from array that fetch in same view controller. But if i put `fetchHistory` in another viewController(right before historyViewController) and send the data via navigation, pickerView shows `confirms` data. How to make it works when i put `fetchHistory` in historyViewController? or any suggest the best way to put `fetchHistory` someway instead put it in random viewController?

**historyViewController**

```
var confirms = [DataWaitingConfirm]() //pickerView DataSource
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchHistory()//fetch data from server for 'confirms'
}
```

**fetchData**

```
func fetchHistory(){

    let headers = ["Authorization" : "\(TokenType!) \(Token!)"]
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxxx/history/", headers: headers, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
              switch response.result {
                  case .Success:
                     if let value = response.result.value {
                         let json = JSON(value)
                         print(json)
                         for (results,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["results"] {
                         print(subJson["status"].int)
                         if subJson["status"].intValue == 3 {
                             print("ada 3")
                             let orderReference = subJson["px_reference"].stringValue
                             let date = subJson["invoice_date_str"].stringValue
                             let totalPaid = subJson["total_paid"].stringValue

                             let orderPicker = "\(orderReference) \(date) \(totalPaid)"
                             let confirm = DataWaitingConfirm(orderReference: orderReference, pickerConfirm: orderPicker)
                             self.confirms += [confirm]
                                            }
                                        }}

            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            spinningActivity.hide(true)
            print(error)
            self.displayAlertMessage("could not fetch history")
        }
    }
}
```

**pickerview delegate**

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    let orderToConfirm = confirms[row]
    return orderToConfirm.pickerConfirm
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {


    return confirms.count
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` to trigger the refresh. The datasource methods will then be called again and your updated data will appear in the picker view.

Your Alamofire request returns asynchronously and hence you should trigger the reload after `self.confirms += confirm`.

Note: You might also consider triggering it on the main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {...})`

Answer (score 0):

You should use after ws response:

reloadComponent:

or

reloadAllComponents: